# Adding a namespace to already released packages

Tags: salesforcedx, namespace

We already have released one unlocked package in production for six months, without namespaces. We are considering developing new unlocked packages, and we were thinking about using namespaces and maybe converting the previous one to add a namespace:

1. Is it possible simply to bring all the data from the non-namespaced fields to the namespaced fields?
2. Will the API name of fields need to reference the namespace from within the package (a validation rule, for example?)
3. Will the API name of fields need to reference the namespace from outside the package (an API call for an integraiton, for example?)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible simply to bring all the data from the non-namespaced fields to the namespaced fields?

No. You can't change or add a namespace to an existing package, and the new package you'll need to create will create namespaced versions of those fields. You'll have to uninstall the old package, install the new one, and copy the data manually.

> Will the API name of fields need to reference the namespace from within the package (a validation rule, for example?)

You never need to use the namespace within your own package. The deployment process handles this for you automatically.

> Will the API name of fields need to reference the namespace from outside the package (an API call for an integraiton, for example?)

Yes.